# Invoking System.Delegate class object in C#

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke, late-binding

I am trying to build an object that uses System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke, which has the method: (amongst others)

```
    public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
```

What is the best way to call the method with the given arguments? I can use:

```
    public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
    }
```

But this is late bound. My gut instinct is that this is the only way to call the method.. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Beware that you are making pretty stiff promises when you implement the interface.  You are actually expected to *synchronize* code.  Focus on implementing the InvokeRequired property first, that's the hard one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it’s logically impossible for it to be any other way. The `method` delegate may encapsulate a method of any signature (with any number and type of parameters, and any type of return value or void). The only way to resolve its signature and invoke it with the supplied arguments (after verifying that they’re of the correct quantity and type) would be at run-time through reflection.

If you were not implementing the `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface and could define your own method, then you could restrict your `method` argument to only accept method delegates of a particular signature; in that case, you could invoke them directly.

For example, to execute methods that take no parameters and have a return value, you would use:

```
public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult> method)
{
    return method();
}
```

To execute a method that takes three parameters and has no return value, you would use:

```
public void Invoke<T1,T2,T3>(Action<T1,T2,T3> method, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
{
    method(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

Comment: After a bit more digging around, yep, this is the conclusion I've come to as well. Thanks for the succinct response.